How to I accelerate convergence of a slowly converging neural network problem?
As the attached figure suggests, My neural network learns very slowly, takes a lot of iterations and the error is too high. I would appreciate if I could get some advice of how to tackle these issues. I have tried increasing the network size but that didn't help.


Can you please share the information regarding your model, its type, its architecture, which loss function and accuracy matrix you are using, etc? it would give better understanding of the issue
